# UISplitViewController always horizontally compact when inside UITabBarController - iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uisplitviewcontroller, size-classes

I found a weird issue, when I have a `UISplitViewContorller` inside a `UITabBarController`, it always has compact horizontal size class. I can't find any documentation for why this is, nor a way to avoid it. I tried `setOverrideTraitCollection(customTrait, forChild: childViewController)` but that seems to work for every other controller except for `UISplitViewContorller`.

Is there any reason for this? Any way to get around it?

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you're not expected to do that. Split view controller inside a tab bar controller sounds pretty weird.

Comment: Indeed, what Apple suggests is just the opposite: on iPad, use split view controller plain and simple (side by side); on iPhone, where we are compact, use a tab bar controller plain and simple (as the `.compact` v.c.).